# Fluent assertion equivalent for Nunit delayed constraint

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow, fluent-assertions

I am trying to find a way to use

```
 var constraint = Is.True.After(delayInMilliseconds: 30000, pollingInterval: 5000);
 Assert.That(() => vehicleInfo.Exists(x => x.ImageId == fileName), constraint);
```

in fluent assertions. Is it possible to user Extensibility of fluent assertions to achieve the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "user Extensibility of fluent assertions"?

Comment: Basically you want to "wait" until a condition is true?

Comment: FileName doesn't get populated immediately and I want to poll and check inside the assertion. Yes, I want to "wait" until a condition is true.

I could do as mentioned above using Assert.That(), looking for something similar using fluent assertions.  @GregBurghardt

Comment: Interesting GitHub feature request from 2018: [NotThrow with wait time](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/940). Looks like something similar. They specifically mention NUnit delayed constraints.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Thanks for pointing me in the write direction.